# Calculate angle betwen two lines

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

[image]

I have been trying to find the best solution to this problem, but my math is pretty bad.

What I want to do is calculate the "Angle" in radians, I have all the 3 co-ordinates and all the 3 lengths of the triangle.
I am confused as to how to set up the calculation in Python so that I can find out the angle.

The main motive is to figure out the direction of rotation of line (x1,y1)-(x3,y3) to meet the line (x1,y1)-(x2,y2). Simply put should I rotate it right or left?

The logic should work in all 4 Quadrants and not in only one <- This is where I am stuck
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do you know the dot product?

Comment: yeah, but I can't get it working in all quadrants

Comment: Just to be clear, when the points are $(x_1,y_1)=(0,0)$, $(x_2,y_2)=(1,0)$, and $(x_3,y_3)=(-1,1)$, which direction should you rotate?

Comment: @MikeEarnest To the right side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I was unclear about the question, and my solution should be correct now.

Let's call the points $(x_1,y_1)=P_1,(x_2,y_2)=P_2,$ and $(x_3,y_3)=P_3$. The quantity
$$
A=(x_3-x_1)(y_2-y_1)-(y_3-y_1)(x_2-x_1)
$$
tells you which side of the line $\overline{P_1P_2}$ that $P_3$ is on: when $A>0$, then when you stand at $P_1$ and look at $P_2$, then $P_3$ is on your right; when it is negative, $P_3$ is on your left.

So, $A$ is enough to determine the best direction to rotate. The result can be summed up nicely:

> When $A>0$, rotate left, when $A<0$, rotate right.

This comes from looking at the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the vectors $\vec v=(x_3-x_1,y_3-y_1,0)$, the vector from point 1 to point 3 *in three dimensional space*, and $\vec w=(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,0)$, the vector from point 1 to point 2.

Comment: I tried to understand it, but kinda find it too arcane. I tried to implement it, and it gave me bad results in my simulation.
I am guessing your P1,P2 and P3 are same as my (x1,y1) (x2,y2) and (x3 , y3)

Comment: @chettyharish I think this should be correct now. For example, when $(x_1,y_1)=(0,0)$, $(x2,y2)=(1,0)$, and $(x3,y3)=(−1,1)$, we get $A=(-1-0)(0-0)-(1-0)(1-0)=-1$, so you should rotate right, as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Translate it onto the Cartesian plane, letting A be$(x_1,y_1)$, B be $(x_2, y_2)$, C be $(x_3, y_3)$.

By calculating the gradients of lines AB and AC, you can then find the angles that they mark with the x-axis (since $\text{Gradient}=\tan \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle that they make with the x axis).

Note: You will need to consider a triangle and apply some elementary trigonometry, but you will get it.